# Semi-Simple Kahler Groups?

Tags: lie-groups, dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, complex-geometry

We say that a Kahler manifold is a *Kahler group* if it is also a Lie group. I would like to know which semi-simple Lie groups are also Kahler groups?

Comment: I was about to reply, but then I saw that you meant something quite
different than what I thought. Kahler group usually means
fundamental group of a compact Kahler manifold. But anyway, for the
question you asked, do you want the metric to be invariant under
the group action?

Comment: Yes, it should be invariant.


Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semisimple Lie groups admit bi-invariant metrics (although not necessarily positive-definite) and it is not hard to show that if a Lie group admits a bi-invariant metric and also a left-invariant Kähler structure, then the group is abelian, contradicting the assumption that it was semisimple.  Hence no semisimple Lie group admits a left-invariant Kähler structure.

In the case where the Kähler structure is not left-invariant, the two structures do not talk to each other and hence you are asking whether a manifold which admits the structure of a semisimple Lie group could also admit a Kähler structure.  The identity component of such a manifold is (rationally) homotopy equivalent to a product of odd spheres (of dimension at least 3), so $H^2$ vanishes and thus, if compact, they again cannot admit a Kähler structure.

I'm not sure about the noncompact case, though; but it looks unlikely to me at this time.

Comment: In fact, it is enough for the group to be unimodular in order to deduce that if it has a left-invariant Kähler structure it is abelian.  This is proved in a paper by Lichnerowicz and Medina (http://www.springerlink.com/content/p7p8gl6h5163j465/)


Comment: The link to the article by Lichnerowicz and Medina at `springerlink.com` mentioned in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71006/semi-simple-kahler-groups/71013#comment179650_71028) above is broken, but it can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF00398959](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00398959) ([Zbl 0665.53046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0665.53046)).

Answer (score 1):

See http://eom.springer.de/h/h047640.htm and references therein.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Homogeneous_complex_manifold.