# Symplectic Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry

Assume that $G$ is a Lie group and at the same time it admits a symplectic structure.

> Does $G$ necessarily admit a symplectic structure such that the right multiplication preserves the symplectic structure?

Comment: Let $G$ be the universal covering of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. Then $G\times \mathbf{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^4$ and hence admits a symplectic structure (as a manifold). However every Lie group with a right-invariant symplectic structure is solvable (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1629 for references), so $G\times \mathbf{R}$ has no such structure.

Comment: Why don‘t you make this an answer?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71766/which-lie-algebra-admit-symplectic-forms and if you know the French language, see http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1979__29_4_17_0.pdf or this PhD thesis but in French language https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00078872/document

Comment: This is the nice paper which answer to your question https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9719-9_17

Comment: The original reference that 4-dimensional symplectic Lie groups are solvable is B. Chu, *Symplectic homogeneous spaces, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 197 (1974), 145-159*
 http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1974-197-00/S0002-9947-1974-0342642-7/

Comment: Also this is the correct definition: A Lie group $G$ admits an invariant symplectic structure if there exists on $G$ a left invariant closed 2- form whose rank is equal to the dimension of $G$. Also there is a notion of Poisson Lie group and Poisson Lie algebra(I remember I have had lecture course about it 5 years ago when I was master student in Marseille)

Comment: If you are looking for Lie group which admit Kahler structure see André Lichnerowicz paper (written in French) https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0097472

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $H$ be the universal covering of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\times\mathbf{R}$. Then $H$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^4$ and hence has a symplectic structure (as a manifold). However, every Lie group with a right-invariant symplectic structure is solvable (see Baues-Cortès ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1629)) for references), so $H$ has no such structure.

Comment: (+1) and thank you very much for your attention to my question and your very interesting answer.